# Does Android come with free navigation in non-US contries?

Tags: gps, navigation, google-maps-navigation

The fact that free gps turn-by-turn navigation is available for new enough Android devices using Google-owned map data is well known.

Does Android offer free navigation in non-US countries as well?

Comment: If it makes any difference, it's Italy I am talking about. I'm not specifying it in the question body before somebody decides to go Too Localized on me :)

Comment: You're not limited to just Google-owned map data. Do a search for applications & questions referencing OpenStreetMap (OSM) here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google Maps Navigation is currently available in the United States, Canada, UK, Ireland, Austria, Belgium, Denmark, France, Germany, Italy, the Netherlands, Portugal, Spain, and Switzerland.

Comment: Okay, but is it free and bundled with new smartphones?

Comment: @badp - Whether or not something is bundled depends on the manufacturer and carrier. However, my dad's new Galaxy S came with it, and it's available on the market.

Comment: @badp I got it as a free update (downloadable trough the Market) when it came out here in the Netherlands. and yes, it's free.

Answer (score 2):

I have an unbranded German HTC Desire. It has Google Navigation installed by default (IIRC, it came with the Froyo upgrade -- I don't remember seeing it in the preinstalled Android 2.1.).

Comment: It's definitely available for 2.1 phones, if you're in a supported country and don't have Navigation, go to the Market and download the latest version of Maps.

Comment: @GAThrawn Yeah, it might actually have come with a Maps update, not the OS upgrade.