# is Google map navigation only available to selected country

Tags: google-maps-navigation

I love using Google map to give me direction. however, I would like it to provide "turn left, turn right" voice while I am driving. I heard Google map navigation able to provide such feature. I search from android market but cannot find one. is it only available to selected country? is there any workaround, or other software I can try out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's limited to specific locations, and only available with a data connection.  See [this question on the location limitations](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/does-android-come-with-free-navigation-in-non-us-contries) and [this question on alternatives](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227/what-replacements-are-available-for-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

Google's official list of countries with Google Maps Navigation (Beta) available is here:
http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=172221

Currently 29 countries are listed there.

If your country is not in the list, the simplest workaround I found is [brut.all ownhere modified changepn Google Maps apps on XDADev](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1007132) .